# No dialog role is announced by JAWS screen reader when dialog is appear in the screen

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, material-ui, jaws-screen-reader, wcag2.0

I have created a dialog component in react using MUI library. I am working on WCAG 2.0 integration and testing the component in Chrome + JAWS.

No role "dialog" is announced by the screen reader software JAWS when dialog appears in the screen while it is working fine as expected in Safari + VO.

I tried my things but there is no clue of how to fix this. Below is a sample codesandbox url of the same.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-dialog-vy69wd

I am using chrome (v115.x.x.x) and JAWS 2022.

Comment: I have an older version of JAWS 2020 but it works ok in Chrome 115 for me. It says, *""Modal title close, **dialog**; close, heading level 2, Button; To activate press Enter"*. Hopefully it's not a regression with JAWS 2022. Do you hear the same thing but without the "dialog" role announced? Can you post exactly what JAWS says? **Side note:** it's a little unusual to have your X-close button embedded in your <h2>.

Comment: It announces as per expectation except *dialog* role. And you are correct the button element wouldn't be inside h2 element. Above sandbox link was just for reference in the question.